# Как в Asp Net Core подключиться к MS SQL Server и увидеть данные?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-core

Вот уже несколько дней копипастю код, который не работает.
Нужно получить данные из таблицы сервера и присвоить их обьекту,массиву или списку.
Без всяких Entity Framwork. Просто запрос на Sql и запись таблицы в переменную.
Спасибо.

Comment: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper

Answer (score 2):

Вы должны включить SqlClient в project.json.

```
 "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.3": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Data.SqlClient": "4.1.0-*"
      }
    }
  }
```

Тогда Вы будете иметь возможность использовать соединение SQL:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   {
           connection.Open();
           using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.Test", con))
           {
                  var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                  // map your reader
           }
    }
```